# Не работает модуль jQuery UI. В чем проблема?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Пытаюсь у себя на сайте сделать такое [всплывающее диалоговое окно](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated). Но оно не работает ни на [сайте](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua) (кнопка в футере), ни на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bht3bnqw/3/).  Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

А [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/bht3bnqw/5/) всё работает.

В jsfiddle скрипты подключаются не в окно, а слева, можно выбрать библиотеку или добавить свою ссылку на скрипт.

Comment: А можете глянуть, почему на сайте не работает?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить скрипт диалога ниже html-вёрстки, у вас в консоли пишет: 

>"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of null"

Answer (score 2):

Я разобрался, в чем проблема, - библиотеки конфликтовали, написал `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`, и все заработало, но когда закрываю модальное окно, не происходит красивого эффекта.